# What's the use of the fire-extinguishers in Half-Life?

Tags: half-life

In *Half-Life*, *Half-Life: Opposing Force*, and *Half-Life: Blue Shift*, fire extinguishers in glass boxes can be found mounted on the walls:

[image: A screenshot of a fire extinguisher in Opposing Force]

If damaged, they will explode, causing a small amount of cold damage to the player, indicated by a snowflake symbol on the HUD.

Is there any use for these?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Half life wiki page on [Fire Extinguishers](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Fire_Extinguisher), fire extinguishers in the original Half Life were not usable items (emphasis mine):

> The Fire Extinguisher is an item (used as a weapon game-wise) cut from Half-Life 2. It can be found in the playable Half-Life 2 Beta. **It first appeared in Half-Life as an unusable item.**

However, just because it is unusable does not mean it does not serve any function. As you mentioned in your question, when damaged they can explode, causing cold damage to anything close to them. I could not find any sources confirming this, but I do know from my own playing that at the very least this explosion will damage you as the player (though I do not know if it will also damage enemies as well - I don't remember a time when there were enemies around I could attempt to damage using the wall-mounted fire extinguisher).

Answer (score 1):

Fire extinguishers provide no function whatsoever.

In this case they serve the exact same reason as the toolbox right next to them in your image provided, decoration and immersion in the environment.

Comment: Asker notes that destroying the extinguisher applys damage to his character. Technically that would mean the fire extinguishers **function**, and are at least more than a simple aesthetic model. Have you confirmed the extinguishers do not damage enemies, if nearby? Your original version implies you are simply making assumptions (adding that they are functional in GTA offers no real solution in context of the question, so I have removed it)

Answer (score 1):

Their function works similiarly like explosion Barrel with difference in range of damage and damage itself.

Comment: Why the downvote here ?